# Question about linear functions as a sub vector space

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

> Prove or disprove the set $U$ of all functions
>   $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the form $f(x)=ax+b$ with constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is a sub vector space of the $\mathbb R$ vector
>   space $V$ of all real functions containing solely addition and scalar
>   multiplication.

I am certain that the statement is true since with only addition and scalar multiplication no higher degree functions such as $f(x)=x^2$ can be formed.

However, I am unsure how exactly to prove the statement in a logical manner.

Comment: More generally, the set of all polynomial functions of degree at most $n$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prove it like you prove any other set is a vector subspace:

1. You take any two functions $f, g$ in the set $U$, and you prove that $f+g$ is in $U$.
2. You take any function $f$ in $U$, and any scalar $\alpha$, and you prove that $\alpha \cdot f$ is in $U$

You also have to show that $U$ is non-empty, but that should be very easy.

---

So, the outline of your proof would be: (you fill in the details)

> Let $f,g\in U$. Then, $f=$______ and $g=$_______. Therefore, $f+g$__________ _________________. Therefore, $f+g\in U$
>
> Now let $f\in U$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Then, ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
>   Therefore, $\alpha f\in U$ and $U$ is a vector subspace.

Comment: Just a small point: you also need to show that $U$ is non-empty (typically by showing $0 \in U$).